# How to get Google Places API (nearby search) data to Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, google-places-api

I have Excel sheet with a lot of addresses (and the matching coordinates). I want to use Google Places API to create a function that gets me e. g. all restaurants surrounding a specific address. I try to output the names of all matching restaurants, the issue is that the output is just "0".

Here is my code:

```vb
Function Nearby(Lat As Long, Lng As Long) As Variant

    'Variablen definieren
    Dim Request                 As New XMLHTTP30
    Dim Results                 As New DOMDocument30
    Dim StatusNode              As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim NearbyNode              As IXMLDOMNode

    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Request.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=" & Lat & "," & Lng & "&radius=50&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyA5nFPM_9Ss_X410c35WfoP_obP5UwppRU"""
    Request.send
    Results.LoadXML Request.responseText

    Set StatusNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//status")
    Select Case UCase(StatusNode.Text)
        Case "OK"  

            Set NearbyNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/name[1]/name[2]/name[3]/name[4]")
            Nearby = NearbyNode.Text
        Case "ZERO_RESULTS"  
            Nearby = "The address does not exists"
        Case Else             
            Nearby = "Error"
    End Select

errorHandler:
    Set StatusNode = Nothing
    Set NearbyNode = Nothing
    Set Results = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly reworked your code, try the below example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestNearby()

    Dim NearbyNames
    Dim NearbyState As String

    Nearby "-33.8670522", "151.1957362", "1000", "hospital", NearbyNames, NearbyState
    If NearbyState = "OK" Then
        MsgBox Join(NearbyNames, vbCrLf)
    Else
        MsgBox NearbyState
    End If

End Sub

Sub Nearby(Lat As String, Lng As String, Dist As String, PointType As String, Names As Variant, State As String)

    Dim Request As Object
    Dim Results As Object
    Dim Node

    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Set Request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Request.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?" & _
        "location=" & Lat & "," & Lng & _
        "&radius=" & Dist & _
        "&type=" & PointType & _
        "&key=AIzaSyA5nFPM_9Ss_X410c35WfoP_obP5UwppRU", False
    Request.send
    Set Results = Request.responseXML
    Select Case UCase(Results.SelectSingleNode("//status").Text)
        Case "OK"
            With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                For Each Node In Results.SelectNodes("//PlaceSearchResponse/result/name")
                    .Add .Count, Node.nodeTypedValue
                Next
                Names = .Items()
            End With
            State = "OK"
        Case "ZERO_RESULTS"
            State = "No results"
        Case Else
            State = "Wrong request"
    End Select
    Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    State = "Error"

End Sub
```

The output for me is:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I changed `Lat,Lng` to type `double` and modified the `Request.Open "GET"` string

```
Sub Nearby()

Dim Request                 As New XMLHTTP30
Dim Results                 As New DOMDocument30
Dim StatusNode              As IXMLDOMNode
Dim NearbyNode              As IXMLDOMNode
Dim Node                    As IXMLDOMNode

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    Dim Lat As Double   'Chicago
    Lat = 41.878114
    Dim Lng As Double
    Lng = -87.629798

    Request.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=" & Lat & "," & Lng & "&radius=50&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyA5nFPM_9Ss_X410c35WfoP_obP5UwppRU" & "&sensor=False"
    Request.send
    Results.LoadXML Request.responseText

    Set StatusNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//status")

    Select Case UCase(StatusNode.Text)

        Case "OK"
            For Each Node In Results.SelectNodes("//PlaceSearchResponse/result/name")
                Debug.Print Node.nodeTypedValue
            Next

        Case "ZERO_RESULTS"
            Debug.Print "The address does not exists"

        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Error"

    End Select

errorHandler:
    Set StatusNode = Nothing
    Set NearbyNode = Nothing
    Set Results = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you!  but there is no way to get this information with a function? I have a lot of addresses, so it would be easier for me to have a function.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a string of comma separated values (albeit needs more error trapping) :

```
Public Function NearBy(Lat As Double, Lng As Double) As Variant

Dim Request                 As New XMLHTTP30
Dim Results                 As New DOMDocument30
Dim StatusNode              As IXMLDOMNode
Dim NearbyNode              As IXMLDOMNode
Dim Node                    As IXMLDOMNode
Dim sz                      As String

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    Request.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=" & Lat & "," & Lng & "&radius=150&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyA5nFPM_9Ss_X410c35WfoP_obP5UwppRU" & "&sensor=False"
    Request.send
    Results.LoadXML Request.responseText

    Set StatusNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//status")

    Select Case UCase(StatusNode.Text)

        Case "OK"
            For Each Node In Results.SelectNodes("//PlaceSearchResponse/result/name")
                sz = sz & Node.nodeTypedValue & ", "
            Next
            NearBy = Left(sz, Len(sz) - 2) 'remove last ", "

        Case "ZERO_RESULTS"
            NearBy = "The address does not exists"

        Case Else
            NearBy = "Error"

    End Select

errorHandler:
    Set StatusNode = Nothing
    Set NearbyNode = Nothing
    Set Results = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing

End Function
```